# Flutter: callback when user drags into a widget

Tags: flutter, gesture

I want to play another piano note when the user simply drags their fingers on it.

Currently, I am using `Listener` with `onPointerMove`, But it is not perfect for what I need.

`onPointerMove` is Called when a pointer that triggered an `onPointerDown` changes position.

What I need is; a callback when the pointer is in that widget without tapping on the widget (piano note in this case). This means `onPointerDown` isn't called.

[image: piano image]

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Listener(
    key: _widgetKey,
    onPointerDown: (event) {
      play();
    },
    onPointerUp: (event) {
      stop();
    },
    onPointerMove: (event) {
      if (_widgetKey.currentContext == null ||
          _widgetKey.currentContext?.size == null) return;
      if (_widgetKey.currentContext!.size!.width < event.localPosition.dx ||
          event.localPosition.dx < 0 ||
          _widgetKey.currentContext!.size!.height < event.localPosition.dy ||
          event.localPosition.dy < 0) {
        debugPrint("touch is outside");
        stop();
      } else {
        if (!activePlay) play();
        // debugPrint = true;
      }
    },
  );
}
```